# Can we guess the religion or caste of Naseeruddin Shah's character in the movie "A Wednesday"?

Tags: character, a-wednesday

The lead character in *A Wednesday* does say that he won't reveal his name, but I guess there are subtle clues about his identities. Has anyone given thought in that direction?

Comment: Can you give any example of what his caste may be?

Comment: @Mistu4u - I am only guessing.

Answer (score 7):

**NO**. His caste is never revealed nor can be guessed. It could have been guessed by listening to his accent or his demeanor. But he spoke Urdu to terrorist which anybody from North India is capable of. His dress was normal like any normal person. He did not use any specific word or appearance that can bind him to any particular religion. His wife was wearing normal Indian apparel. So I can see nothing to make him bound to any cast.

Comment: Yes you are right and even movies moral is not to set any religious values, that's why they never cleared his religion .

Comment: Story of movie is for how normal person should reply to terrorist, so Caste of naseeruddin's is not important in film it's only INDIAN.