# Is The Common Man's identity hinted in the movie A Wednesday?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, a-wednesday

In the Hindi movie *[A Wednesday!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wednesday!)*, Naseeruddin Shah played the role of "The Common Man", and Anupam Kher plays the role of "Prakash Rathod, Commissioner of Mumbai Police".

When Prakash asks The Common Man about his identity, he says "I don't want you to associate any kind of religion to what I am doing."

Even in the end when both of them meet, Prakash says he will not reveal his identity as people will associate religion with it.

Naseeruddin Shah is credited as "The Common man". If you go a little back, The Common Man calls Naina Roy (Deepal Shaw) from UTV news, informing her to visit 
a certain place to cover the bomb story and refers her as "*beti*" (daughter in Hindi), to which Naina says "*apne mujhe beti kaha*" to which Common Man says "yes" and hangs up the phone.

In any way did the makers of movie try to give a hint to the identity of the Common Man?

Comment: Related [Can we guess the religion or caste of Naseer Uddin's character in the movie “A wednsday”?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9575/can-we-guess-the-religion-or-caste-of-naseer-uddins-character-in-the-movie-a-w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they didn't and it isn't even required.

The full concept of the film is about a frustrated common man. His identity doesn't matter and that gives the character more strength. Even when asked about if he has lost someone in bomb last, he told about a story of some random guy, another common man. As you already know, he hid his name to disassociate it with any religion.

Even if his name and religion got revealed, his act will remain the same but the reception might be different. It would be less impact-full maybe.

Comment: What's the last sentence supposed to say?

Comment: @TomCody in the film this common man play with the mind of police, first he act like a terrorist and want to make them free and then kill them. He just want to prove his point. But whenever this kind of story comes media always highlight what family he belongs too and religion etc and the whole point got destroyed. He is just a common man.

Comment: I just asked what the last sentence in your answer is supposed to say, literally, because I can't comprehend it.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I think if you reveal his religion, people will start gossiping on his intentions (like he hate X religion). If you don't mention it, people have much less to gossip.

Answer (score 0):

No, the makers don't try to give any identity of common man. Regarding calling her daughter ("beti"), it's a general way of talking in India to call son ("beta") or daughter ("beti") for someone of that age group.